# Magento 2.2.5 : Stock Item with id "x" does not exist

Tags: magento2

I have got an issue of "Stock Item with id "x" does not exist" because of this some product have didn't display price and options in product detail page.

Have any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Basically I am not getting your questions.
But primarily, it looks like you need stock details.

So, for that, you can follow the below approach

```
/** @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStatusCriteriaInterfaceFactory $stockStatusCriteriaFactory **/
        $criteria = $stockStatusCriteriaFactory->create();
        $criteria->setProductsFilter($productId);
        /** @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockStatusRepositoryInterface $stockStatusRepository **/
        $result = $stockStatusRepository->getList($criteria);
        $stockStatus = current($result->getItems());
        $stockStatus->getProductId();                 // product id
        $stockStatus->getQty();   // quantity of specified product
        $stockStatus->getStockStatus();     // Could be 
// Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Status::STATUS_OUT_OF_STOCK = 0;
// or
// Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Status::STATUS_IN_STOCK = 1;
```

Credits: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7057#issuecomment-256052729

Comment: Thank you for sharing this, this allows you to get and set stock status for non simple products as well - other methods you can't without an error about how qty records can't be found